# Cannot figure out what's going on with python3-rosdep2

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm following the instructions for installing ROS2 [here](https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Installation/Dashing/Linux-Install-Binary/) and I keep getting the error

```
sudo: rosdep: command not found
```

when I run `sudo update init`. Looking through the files installed in the package python3-rosdep2, I don't see any executable. I tried `sudo python3 -m rosdep2 init` and it says

```
/usr/bin/python3: No module named rosdep2.__main__; 'rosdep2' is a package and cannot be directly executed
```

So I have no idea what to do next. I created an [issue on github](https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/rosdep/issues/772) and was told to ask my question here. After following the instructions given on github I still cannot execute the steps to install and use python3-rosdep2.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/359586/cannot-figure-out-what%27s-going-on-with-python3-rosdep2/) by [towood](https://answers.ros.org/users/3412/towood/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2020-08-15

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The [comment on github has the answer](https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/rosdep/issues/772#issuecomment-668015914). Uninstall `python3-rosdep2`, and install `python3-rosdep` or `python-rosdep`. `python3-rosdep2` is an older version. See this question for more info.

https://answers.ros.org/question/353082/missing-packages-after-installing-rosdep-based-on-python3-rosdep2-in-noetic/

```
sudo apt-get purge python-rosdep2 python3-rosdep2
sudo apt-get install python3-rosdep
```

---

Originally posted by [sloretz](https://answers.ros.org/users/23470/sloretz/) with karma: 3061 on 2020-08-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4